# How to back up song ratings in iTunes?

Tags: backup, itunes

How can I back up my song ratings (0-5 stars) in iTunes? In what file(s) are they stored?

Options *Keep iTunes Media folder organized* and *Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library* are both unchecked in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Song star ratings are stored in the iTunes library database file.

Usually (for Windows vista/7):

> C:\Users\Case\Music\iTunes\iTunes Library.itl

also a good idea is to backup the xml file.
This is the file iTunes reads if the database get corrupted

> C:\Users\Case\Music\iTunes\iTunes Music Library.xml

note if you want to transfer songs/star ratings from one computer to another, change the drive your music is on, or reformat your computer; you probably want to read [this](http://hifiblog.com/past/2006/05/11/howto-move-your-itunes-music-while-preserving-library-data-when-you-dont-let-itunes-manage-your-music-library/) article about how the .itl and .xml files work.

Comment: Thanks. I also found a way to store ratings using ID tags in the audio files themselves if something messes up the library db - in the comment field I marked ratings as 1/5 ... 5/5. Then created a new smart playlist where Comments contain "/5". It's then possible to sort by comments and re-create also the iTunes stars.

Comment: great idea, i might do this too!